# How to check the finish of all task in a loop while\for

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have an ArrayList of Routine objects and I must use this method to update the various status of the task

```
    while(!allRoutineComplete){
        for (Routine routine : routineList) {
            if(!(routine.isBlocked()) && !(routine.isFinished())) {
                routine.run();
                }
        }
        for (Routine routine : routineList) {
            routine.updateStatus();
            if(routine.isFinished()){
                completedRoutineNumber++;
            }
            if(completedRoutineNumber==routineList.size()){
                allRoutineComplete=true;
            }
        }
    }
```

unfortunately the boolean `allRoutineComplete` in the my implementation is setted as true before the finish of all the Routine.

What is wrong in my code?

How to check efficently the finish of all tasks?

Comment: Should your routines be run in their own threads? What about using something like a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)?

Comment: no the routine haven't their own thread... are object with a counter `timeRun` and `timeTotal` and are setted to `isFinished` when `timeRun==timeTotal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  must move the all Routine Complete check, in the first `for` cycle, otherwise the routine finished loop more times.

Try to use this:

```
while(!allRoutineComplete){
            for (Routine routine : routineList) {
                if(!(routine.isBlocked()) && !(routine.isFinished())) {
                    routine.run();
                    if(routine.isFinished()){
                        completedRoutineNumber++;
                    }
                    if(completedRoutineNumber==routineList.size()){
                    allRoutineComplete=true;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (Routine routine : routineList) {
                routine.updateStatus();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you are not setting completedRoutineNumber = 0 at the top of the while loop.  Since you are iterating the whole list of routines, if half the routines are complete and the while loop runs more than twice,  completedRoutineNumber will exceed 
routineList.size() the 3rd time through even though only half the routines are complete.

Comment: This is correct, essentially you are counting routines multiple times that are already completed.

Comment: completedRoutineNumber is setted to 0 at the start... the problem is another

Comment: Asgard, the looping structure you've got here runs multiple times through the while loop without resetting the completeRoutineNumber to 0.  You need to reset completeRoutineNumber to 0 within the while loop, at the top of the while loop.  If you just set it before you start the while loop you won't solve this problem.